Jquery .length keeps returning 0 on LinkedIn page
Apologies for asking this question again as per here and here there are answers.
BUT
This appears to be specific to a page. I am building a simple "button" for the browser bookmark bar that will grab the Name and URL or the page I am on to paste into a spreadsheet easily.
On other sites, I use Javascript to find the text and then I can easily paste anywhere.
example from another site (business.currys.co.uk)
javascript:void(
eval('function copyToClipboard(element) {    
var $temp = $("<input>");    
$("body").append($temp);    
$temp.val(element).select();    
document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();}
    var copyableVal =  $("#product-container > h1").text().trim() + " " + $(".page-title span:last-child").text() + " " + $("#product-container > div.product-info > form > dl > dd:nth-child(2)").text().trim();
copyToClipboard(copyableVal);'))

I want to do that with LinkedIn. To repeat - open any linkedin Profile page.
The Name is in this element
<h1 class="text-heading-xlarge inline t-24 v-align-middle break-words">Jannes Sörensen</h1>

<!-- Full Xpath -->
/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/main/section[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/a/h1

I am testing the uniqueness of the classes with
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var classCount= $('.t-24').length;
  console.log(classCount);
 });

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var classCount = $(':header').length;
  console.log(classCount);
 });

However I keep getting 0 in the console :(
I wonder if Jquery is blocked somehow?

I do not find a product-container on a linked-in profile page

I'm assuming you are loading LinkedIn in an iframe. If yes, that wouldn't be possible

Thanks for the direction mPlungjan. I have taken your answer as inspiration and created some "plain javascript" to make it work.
With some help from perplexity.ai too.
I have created this "grab" - save it as a bookmark and by clicking it, you will get a clipboard entry that is:
Person Name, Position, URL
Then you can save people you are connecting with easily for later reference or importing to other CRMs.
javascript:(function(){
    var lnData = "";
    lnData += document.getElementsByClassName("t-24")[0].innerText;
    lnData += "%09";
    lnData += document.getElementsByClassName("text-body-medium")[0].innerText;
    lnData += "%09";
    lnData += document.location.href;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(lnData).then(function() {
        alert("Copied to clipboard");
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
    });
})();


let lnData = \${document.querySelector(".t-24").innerText.trim()}\t${document.querySelector(".text-body-medium").innerText.trim()}\t${document.location.href}`;`

Yes, using jQuery I guess there is an option too :)

The $ here is not jQuery.  The \${somevariable}`` is what is called a template literal

Thanks for that, super interesting - we learn every day :)

You need to click it to get it.
Here is a plain js version which does not rely on jQuery
You need to check the selectors. I for example do not find a product-container on a linkedin profile page
Here is a script that will not run on SO due to security
javascript: (() => {
  const copyToClipboard = (text) => {
    window.focus();
    navigator.clipboard
      .writeText(text)
      .then(() => alert("Copied to clipboard"))
      .catch((err) => console.error('Failed to copy: ', err));
  };
  let container = document.getElementById('product-container'),
    copyableVal = `${container.querySelector('h1').textContent.trim()} ${document.querySelector(".page-title span:last-child").textContent.trim()} ${container.querySelector('div.product-info > form > dl > dd:nth-child(2)').textContent.trim()}`;
  console.log(copyableVal);
  copyToClipboard(copyableVal);
})()

<div id="product-container">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <div class="page-title">
    <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>last span</span>
  </div>
  <div class="product-info">
    <form>
      <dl>
        <dd>DD1</dd>
        <dd>DD2</dd>
        <dd>DD3</dd>
        <dd>DD4</dd>
      </dl>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


Sorry maybe adding the working example was confusing.
The product-container div is on the business.currys.co.uk site - not on LinkedIn.
The problem is that I cannot seem to get a length on any selector on LinkedIn. Once I have got around that limitation, I am sure I can identify and grab stuff somehow - maybe your way will work for sure :)

Please give me the example HTML and I can change my script.

go to any linkedin profile page.
But anyway, I already figured it out now
